# Base model with @Audited

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-envers

I use @Audited annotation for my base model. I extend that for all my entities. but it not work. Is there any method I can use that

this is my base model

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Getter
@Setter
@Audited 
public abstract class BaseModelObject implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4194525198831057382L;


    @Id     
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    protected Long id;
}
```

This is my model class

```
@Entity
public class City extends BaseModelObject {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column
    private String name;
 }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `@Audited` annotation doesn't work the way you believe it should.  By using it on a super class, it has no impact to the child classes which extend it, at least to control whether the child *is* or *is not* audited.  This is by design.

Consider the notion where we have a superclass type and two different implementations, one which we want to audit with its superclass properties and one which we don't.

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Audited
public class Animal {}

@Entity
@Audited
public class Cat extends Animal {}

@Entity
public class Dog extends Animal {}
```

In this example, since `@Audited` isn't inherited, merely placing the annotation on the superclass and the `Cat` entity result in just `Cat` being audited.  The `Dog` entity and its superclass property values are not.

If `@Audited` were treated as an inherited annotation, we'd have to introduce a series of `@AuditOverride` annotations to accomplish the same example, see below.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Animal {}

@Entity
@Audited
@AuditOverride(...)
public class Cat extends Animal {}

@Entity
public class Dog extends Animal {}
```

What makes this worse is if `Animal` had a subset of its properties audited, which would influence the number of `@AuditOverride`s.

This becomes even more complicated when you start to look at entity inheritance strategies and how those come into play with whether to audit an entity or not, and to what degree at what level of the hierarchy.

There is an entire discussion [HHH-6331](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6331) and [HHH-9770](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9770).

In short, if you want your child classes audited, they'll need to be explicitly annotated.

Comment: can we store audit data in separate database instead of main database?

Comment: Depending on your database, you can specify the `catalog` or `schema` setting either in the configuration properties to be global or on a per audited entity basis.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

Superclass:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class AuditableEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @CreatedDate
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private LocalDateTime lastModifiedDate;

    @CreatedBy
    private String createdBy;

    @LastModifiedBy
    private String lastModifiedBy;

    ...
 }
```

Entity class:

```
@Entity
public class City extends AuditableEntity {

    @Id

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    ...
}
```

Configuration:

```
@EnableJpaAuditing
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EntityScan("foo.entities")
@ComponentScan("foo")
@EnableJpaRepositories("foo.repositories")
public class ConfigApp {

    ...
}
```

Auditor service:

```
@Service
public class AuditorServiceImpl implements AuditorAware<String> {

    @Override
    public String getCurrentAuditor() {
        return SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
    }
}
```

Comment: This one Auditing with JPA. in this method which i got big problem. because data are written in same table. can't get history data. In Hibernate Envers provide history data also. this question base on Hibernate Envers. Can we use both together. http://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa